# How do I make my image "grow" from the bottom up using Jquery animate?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple column that's comprised of three images.  What I need is for the column to actually grow up from the bottom up and stay at the height it's grown at (what I mean is, that when the page loads, the column animates in height and stays that way).  I'm stuck and can't seem to figure out how to do this despite reading what I could on this.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Column</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".second").animate({
                    height: '250px'
                });
         });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            #container {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 100 px;
                left: 100px;
            }
            .first {
                background-image:url(first.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100px;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            .second {
                background-image:url(second.png);
                background-repeat:repeat-y;
                height: 20px;
                margin-top: -30px;
            }
            .third {
                background-image:url(third.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="first">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="second">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="third">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LGph5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking on @php_nub_qq - you also have a typo in your CSS:

```
#container { bottom: 100px; }
```

But to solve your problem, since you already use an absolute on your `#container`, just make the others relative and use `top: ##px;` instead of `margin-top`.

**You can see this in [the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LGph5/2/)**

### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container div").animate({
        height: '250px'
    }, 1300);
});
```

### CSS:

```
 #container {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .first {
     top: 100px;
     position: relative;
 }
 .second {
     top: -30px;
     position: relative;
 }
 .third {
     position: relative;
 }
```

I limited the CSS to only things that changed.  If you don't see it, it's the same.  Highlights:  add an `overflow:hidden` to the container to hide the three images from the world until they hatch from their eggs.  Then `position: relative;` and `top: 100px / top: -30px` does the rest.  They'll follow the container as it grows until they reach their limits at their respective `top`s.

Comment: worked like a charm!!!  thank you so much for the help and incredibly useful lesson :) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".second").animate({
            height: '250px'
        });
    }); // < what you're missing
</script>
```